# IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to make some code where I get certain columns from a .csv file and manipulate some data
but there is always an index error with index 3,6,7,8 and 9 and I don't understand why

```
ponto_medicao = 'Ponto de Medição'
calendario = 'Data'
hora = 'Hora'
tipo_de_energia  = 'Tipo de Energia'
ativa_geracao = 'Ativa Geração (kWh)'
ativa_consumo = 'Ativa Consumo (kWh)'
reativa_geracao = 'Reativa Geração (kVArh)'
reativa_consumo = 'Reativa Consumo (kVArh)' 
origem_coleta = 'Origem da Coleta'
notif_coleta = 'Notificação de Coleta'


tabela = pd.read_csv(
    "2498455.csv",
    skiprows=[0,1,2])


mode = tabela[ponto_medicao].value_counts().index[0]
tabela[ponto_medicao].fillna(value=mode, inplace=True)

mode = tabela[calendario].value_counts().index[1]
tabela[calendario].fillna(value=mode, inplace=True)

mode = tabela[hora].value_counts().index[2]
tabela[hora].fillna(value=mode, inplace=True)

mode = tabela[ativa_geracao].value_counts().index[4]
tabela[ativa_geracao].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)

mode = tabela[ativa_consumo].value_counts().index[5]
tabela[ativa_consumo].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)

mode = tabela[origem_coleta].value_counts().index[8]
tabela[origem_coleta].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We can only explain why certain operations are not possible with your data, if we see an example of data that causes the problem.

Comment: Please provide the output of `tabela[tipo_de_energia].value_counts()` and the message error when you try to get its `.index[3]`

Comment: I notice that in some of the code at the end, `.fillna` is called using `value=mode`, but in other cases it is called with `value=0`, ignoring the `mode` value that was just computed. Is this deliberate? What is the overall purpose of the code?

Comment: for now it is deliberate, i was testing to see how that feature works. Im wrtting a code that reads a csv file and use certain data to make a tabule on other file @KarlKnechtel

Comment: Liquida    744
Name: Tipo de Energia, dtype: int64 @FilippeO.Gonçalves

Comment: IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 @FilippeO.Gonçalves

Comment: Maybe try tabela.reset_index(inplace=True) before and adjust your index values accordingly